# How to stress test an ORM data-driven website?

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, stress-testing

I'm used to developing private applications for very small amount of concurrent users (usually no more than 10) on very good servers, so I have never been pressed about stress testing my applications. That being said, this is something I want to have a better grasp on my applications.

FYI, all of my websites are based on ASP.NET 3.5 (WebForms), NHibernate (specially interested in testing it with numerous concurrent sessions) as the ORM of choice and require Active Directory authentication.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I really don't have an idea what is different in stress testing an application with or without ORM

Comment: I'm the newbie asking the question. I don't know, so I include that information just in case. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a pinch, you could do a [selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/) cluster with multiple machines logged in as different users running IE. Come to think of it, that is perhaps the most realistic test if you have the boxes to pull it off . . .

Comment: ... and what if I don't have the boxes to pull it off? I'd only have about 3-4 computers available...

Comment: Virtual Machines are a tester's best friend.

Comment: Any good tutorial I can look into? This looks feasible. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate edition is the way to go for ASP.Net, not only do you get the ability to load test the application, you can also create [performance sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9z62c29.aspx) to profile the application. This is really good for getting a handle on what code is getting called most often, especially database calls.

As the web tests are able to be converted to C# code, you will be able to code up some complex tests driven by a copy of your database to help get some interesting scenarios done as well.

Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate comes with the ability to get up to 250 virtual users running simulatenously, probably enough for your needs.

Comment: Despite of the number of simultaneous users shown by VS, I've got no more than 180 concurrent virtual users per client machine (core 2 duo). I'm sure it was a client side restriction because the server request responses per second kept increasing when more client machines started. I know this number may be different for each scenario and hardware but if you need to simulate 200+ concurrent users, distribute it on distinct machines to avoid wrong results.

Comment: Yeah, it is pretty easy to run the test too hot with a maxed out test harness CPU rather than actually applying load to the target servers.

Comment: Whoa.. I'm out of luck here. At work, we just received our licenses for VS 2010 Professional. :'(